# Vue.js does an event trigger after component has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got some custom components in Vue.js. In one of the components I have is a select list that I want to render as a [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) select box. I use this with a jQuery function `$("select").chosen()`.

```
<template v-for="upload in uploads">
    <new-upload-container :index="$index" :upload="upload" v-if="isNewUpload"></new-upload-container>
    <existing-upload-container :index="$index" :upload="upload" v-if="isExistingUpload"></existing-upload-container>
</template>
```

After I add data to the `uploads` bound array in the Vue instance, the view updates with an instance of the component. Unfortunately when I try to instantiate `Chosen` on the select field, it doesn't work.

I'm not sure if it takes a short time after I add an item to the `uploads` bound array that the DOM actually updates.

```
<template id="existing-upload-container">

      <select name="beats[@{{ index }}][existing_beat]" class="existing-beats">
           <option selected="selected" value="">-- Select a linked beat --</option>
                  @foreach ($beats as $beat)
                   <option value="{{$beat->id}}">{{$beat->name}}</option>
                  @endforeach
       </select>

    </template>
```

Is there an event that is triggered after a component has been fully rendered?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try two things in your component, based on which one works with your package.  In the Vue object:

```
{
    ready:function(){
        // code here executes once the component is rendered
        // use this in the child component
    },
    watch: {
        uploads:function(){
            //code here executes whenever the uploads array changes 
            //and runs AFTER the dom is updated, could use this in
            //the parent component
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after the +1 , it looks like in vuejs 2 `ready` is replaced with `updated` , take a look here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html 

i tested `ready` it didn't work

Comment: @MajedDH I believe the correct one would be `mounted` because updated covers more than that. I couldn't get it working with `ready` but `mounted` worked as expected.

Comment: @asselinpaul, they are different. with mounted you cannot solve the problem of binding something to dynamically created elements from async loaded data. updated works here.

Answer (score 12):

The correct way would be a [custom directive](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html):

```
<select v-chosen name="beats[@{{ index }}][existing_beat]" class="existing-beats">
```

---

```
//insert/require() the following before the creation of your main Vue instance
Vue.directive("chosen",{
  bind: function(){
    $(this.el).chosen();
  }
})
```

edit: directive syntax changed in Vue 2.*:

```
Vue.directive("chosen",{
  bind: function(el){
    $(el).chosen();
  }
})
```

Comment: This sounds like a more elegant solution than [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34997958/368864).

Comment: missing . before chosen()?

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Also note that this syntax only works with Vue 1.

Answer (score 0):

A good good way to do this would be to wrap the Chosen plugin in a Vue component, as described in detail [here](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

use `mounted` callback and check the data status in your code there.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and add further details, or just post it as a comment to the question).