# On render done event after update VueJS Electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuejs2

I have a fairly heavy application where I change multiple overlaying 4K images with VueJS in Electron. I'm taking a screenshot using Electron immediately after the page is re-rendered. I can make this work with a timeout of 1000ms, however this is not very reliable as I can imagine that slower devices need more time to render the page. I have tried nextTick, but this doesn't seem to fire when the render has been completed, only after the data has been updated. Is there a way to tell when the page is done redrawing the changed images, using Vue, Electron, DOMEvents or otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js does an event trigger after component has been rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997541/vue-js-does-an-event-trigger-after-component-has-been-rendered)

Comment: @thanksd I don't think this is a duplicate. My issue is related to the drawing on screen after multiple images are replaced, not rendering the component.

Comment: Can you clarify your question then, adding detail and a code example? Right now it looks like you're asking if the vue instance has a hook for when it's finished rendering, which is a duplicate question of the one I linked.

Comment: If these images are in `img` tags, `img` tags have `load` events. You could listen for completion of all of those load events.

Comment: @BertEvans Good idea. I have created a function that triggers the screenshot when all images are loaded, however the drawing seems to happen after image load which results in not all images displaying in the screenshot.